# Does a character need knowledge of a creature to Summon it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, monsters

When using Summon (Monster/Nature's Ally), does the caster need to actually know what they're 'calling' in order to select the creature? Does the player have agency over which creature(s) answer their player's call?

Comment: [Related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112150/does-a-character-need-knowledge-of-a-creature-to-polymorph-or-wild-shape-into-it) but distinct.

Comment: This is a bit pedantic and doesn't actually change the answer, but per Pathfinder canon Summon Monster/Nature's Ally do not actually "Call" a specific creature (they aren't a real creatures, they're sort-of "idealized copies" from the summoner's mind), since they're Conjuration (Summoning) spells. For a spell to call a real creature, it must be a Conjuration (Calling) spell.

Comment: That's true but I couldn't think of a better word that isn't Summon and I was trying to use a different word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Summon Nature's Ally](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/summonNatureSAlly.html):

> You choose which kind of creature to summon, and you can change that choice each time you cast the spell.

[Summon Monster](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/summon-monster/):

> You choose which kind of creature to summon, and you can choose a different one each time you cast the spell.

So, yes, the player has agency over what they summon.

The spell descriptions don't state any requirement for familiarity. Compare to the language for [Wild Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Druid/#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-) which explicitly states "The form chosen must be that of an animal the druid is familiar with."

Comment: I thought Creature sounded funny but didn't have time to check it. I edited the Q if you want to take your parenthetical out.